# How many ways $10$ adults, $20$ boys and $40$ girls be arranged in a row such that between every $2$ adults there are exactly $2$ boys and $4$ girls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can:
>
> $10$ adults, $20$ boys and $40$ girls be arranged in a row
> such that between every $2$ adults there are exactly $2$ boys and $4$ girls?

I figured the adults go in places $1,7,13...$ and to choose their positions there are $10!$ combinations.  How do I find the sum of all the arrangements including the boys and girls?

Comment: What happens at the ends of the row? Can't you have CCP...PCCCC? (P=parent, C=child)

Comment: Probably the problem should be formulated for a circle, not for a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just assume that there is a parent at the left end of the row and $6$ childs at the right end. For the parents, there are indeed $10!$ possibilities. Next, we determine the order in which the boys appear in the row. There are $20!$ possibilities for that. For the girls, there are $40!$ possibilities. Now we select the first two boys and the first four girls for the first group of children. We have to select in which two of the six places the boys stand. This is possible in $6\choose 2$ ways. Because there are $10$ groups of children, we get $\binom 62^{10}$ ways of doing this. Al together, we get
$$
10!20!40!\binom62^{10}
$$
ways of ordering the people.

If there may be a child at the front of the row, we can rotate the found rows $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ or $6$ places, so we get
$$
7\cdot10!20!40!\binom62^{10}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think Ragnar overcounted. My thinking:

The row may start with parent or group of children, so we have $2$ ways. There are $10!$ ways to order parents. From left to right we choose the group of children in ${40-4n\choose 4}{20-2n\choose 2}$ ways, $n=0,1,...,9$. And in each group there are ${6\choose 2}$ ways to order the six children. Hence, the answer will be
$$\small 2\times 10!\prod_{n=0}^9\left[{40-4n\choose 4}{20-2n\choose 2}{6\choose 2}\right]\\=10!20!40!\left(\frac{5^{10}}{2^{39}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider a permutation PCCCCCCPCCCCCCP (6 children between two successive parents). In this case between the leftmost parent and rightmost parent there are 12 children,, making this permutation and other such permutations invalid.

Hence we can deduce that a valid permutation would have 27 children on each side, then 5 parents and then 3 children.

CCC......(27 times) PPPPP CCC CCC PPPPP CCCCC......(27 times)

Hence the outer children can be arranged in 54! ways, parents can be arranged in 10! ways and inner children can be arranged in C(20,2)*C(40,4)*6! ways

Hence the valid number of permutations are:

6! * 10! * 54! * C(20,2) * C(40,4)